# iOS 9 Pasteboard : not able to write in pasteboard while in background

Tags: ios, ios9, uipasteboard, ios9.1

I want to write in pasteboard while my app is in the background in iOS 9. It worked fine till iOS 8. Something is preventing from writing in the background in iOS 9. I think pasteboard is either locked or deleted, but I am not sure. In iOS 9, I am not able to write in the background until I create pasteboard again.

I know we can't read in the background in iOS 9 but why can't we write as well.

I am getting below warning.

```
 <Warning>: Could not write pasteboard database. Error: Error
 Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save
 the file “pasteboardDB” in the folder “com.apple.UIKit.pboard”."
 UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.UIKit.pboard/pasteboardDB,
 NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x124e066f0 {Error
 Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Comment: I am trying to resolve the same issue. I need to be able to clear the pasteboard on background to stop the user from copy/pasting outside of an app.

Comment: @PPierson did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

UIPasteboard is not accessible when the application is not in the `UIApplicationStateActive` state in iOS9. This is most likely to fix a security issue where an app could observe the pasteboard in the background and scrape any data copied to it.

I needed to clear the pasteboard when entering the background, so I decided to do it in `[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]`, which is called when the app is transitioning from `UIApplicationStateActive` to `UIApplicationStateInactive`. However, this method is also called when a phone call arrives or a push notification alert window is presented.

Note: When testing changes to UIPasteboard from `[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]`, if you put a breakpoint in the method it will continue transitioning to `UIApplicationStateInactive` before the method has finished. This causes the UIPasteboard to be locked again when stepping through your code. If you breakpoint after modifying the UIPasteboard it should be fine.